# Full set of options for creating a jQuery jTable

Tags: jquery, jquery-jtable

I'm able to create a jQuery jTable but I want to configure it differently than the table created by the example I'm working from.

http://jtable.org/GettingStarted

I'm not seeing a place where I might find a list of configurable options that can be used when the table is create in the documentation.

http://jtable.org/Home/Documents

Does this type of documentation exist somewhere?

For example, how do I create the jTable without the "Add new record" option?

This is the code I have so far:

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/headerfooter/header/pageHeader.jsp"%>
<html>

    <head>

        <!-- jQuery-ui dependencies (needed by jQuery jTable) -->
        <script src="${home}/static/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <!-- jQuery jTable dependencies -->
        <link href="${home}/static/jtable.2.4.0/themes/metro/blue/jtable.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="${home}/static/jtable.2.4.0/jquery.jtable.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#PersonTableContainer').jtable({
                    title: 'Table of people',
                    actions: {
                        listAction: '/GettingStarted/PersonList',
                        createAction: '/GettingStarted/CreatePerson',
                        updateAction: '/GettingStarted/UpdatePerson',
                        deleteAction: '/GettingStarted/DeletePerson'
                    },
                    fields: {
                        PersonId: {
                            key: true,
                            list: false
                        },
                        Name: {
                            title: 'Author Name',
                            width: '40%'
                        },
                        Age: {
                            title: 'Age',
                            width: '20%'
                        },
                        RecordDate: {
                            title: 'Record date',
                            width: '30%',
                            type: 'date',
                            create: false,
                            edit: false
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <div id="PersonTableContainer"></div>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your full list of customization options for jTable: 
http://jtable.org/ApiReference/GeneralOptions

Although the documentation is a little scarce on removing the "add new record" button, you could try setting `addRecordButton` to false in the initialization options.

```
$('#PersonTableContainer').jtable({
    addRecordButton: false
});
```

Comment: Doh, I just didn't see the link right at the top of the Documentation section.  I guess I was expecting it to be a tab.

Comment: No problem :) I had to google them myself as well to find them, but I remembered having used them in the past so I knew they had to be somewhere

Comment: addRecordButton: false did not work.  I also tried undefined and that didn't work.  Creating an empty div and using addRecordButton: $('#emptyDivId') did work.